# What does 'authorizing against' mean?

Tags: meaning

I'm sorry if that question seems quite obvious for some of you, but I'm not native from english country and have some trouble with some expressions.

Today, I found this sentence :

> In the end, all software systems that need any type of authorization will be authorizing against activities

In this context, I can't manage to understand the meaning of against, it is supposed to show some kind of opposition, but where do you find an opposition in this sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of software development, "authorizing against X"  is common parlance for

> determining your authorization, using X as the resource to make that determination.

It is a specific instance of "comparing against X" for the purpose of authorization.

As an example:

> Once the user submits a password, we hash it and **compare the value
>   against** the Password_Hashes table to determine if they're authorized.

is frequently shortened to be

> The user's hashed password is authorized against the Password_Hashes
>   table.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that wasn't the first time I saw it but I always guessed the general meaning of the sentence.

Comment: Not to divert from ELU's purpose and discuss the finer points of software development, but in terms of comprehension, passwords are used for _authentication_; that is, providing information in support of identifying _who you are_ to a computer. Once that has been successful, while using the product or service you are accessing your ability to perform actions will be subject to your _authorisation_; which describes what operations are available to the identity that you have assumed upon accessing the system. Both of these may be achieved when you log in but there is a semantic distinction.

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't make sense to me as a native speaker (who works in IT) either!

Maybe it's trying to say that software systems that require authorisation are moving to a model where all activities are blocked unless specifically authorised - BUT THAT IS ONLY A GUESS!

Comment: This is a bit extreme - all it is saying is that the system will restrict **something**.  If not, why bother with the login?  It could be as simple as allowing private files or directories. But any of that requires a complex system of tagging files and actions with rights and checking them.